Why did the Hyperbola-1 launch fail in August 2021?
On August 3, 2021, the Hyperbola-1 rocket failed for the second time. There is no launch video. What went wrong? Why did it fail?

According to i-Space (the company that launches Hyperbola-1), the fairing failed to properly separate, preventing the rocket from getting fast enough to achieve a stable orbit. (source)
